# Prove that there exists an isomorphism of monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I have an exercise as preparation for an exam:

For $ n \in \mathbb{N} $, $ n \geq 1$ is defined the function $ f_n: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x) = \lfloor\frac{x}{n}\rfloor$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and the set $M=\{f_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

I have proven that $(M, \circ) $ is a commutative monoid, but I don't know how to solve the following 2 requirements:

1. Prove that there exists an isomorphism of monoids 
   $$
    (M, \circ) \simeq (\mathbb{N}, \cdot) 
   $$
2. Is $ M $ a submonoid in $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R},\circ) $?

Comment: When you write $[\frac xn]$, do you mean the largest integer less than or equal to $\frac xn$?

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show it's an isomorphism (sending $f_n\to n$) we need to show that for all $x,m,n$ we have that
$$\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor \frac xn\rfloor}m\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor \frac x{mn}\right\rfloor$$
Write
$$x=an+b$$
where $0\le b< n$ and $a$ is an integer. Then $\lfloor \frac xn\rfloor=a$. Write
$$a=cm+d$$
where $0\le d <m$ and $c$ is an integer. Then $\lfloor \frac am\rfloor=c$.

Now write
$$x=(cm+d)n+b=cmn+dn+b$$
We have that $d\le m-1$, and $b\le n-1+\epsilon$ where $0\leq \epsilon <1$ is such that $b-\epsilon$ is an integer. Then 
$$x-cmn\le (m-1)n+n-1+\epsilon=mn-1+\epsilon<mn$$
Thus
$$\left\lfloor \frac x{mn}\right\rfloor=c$$
and we are done.

This monoid is not a submonoid of the monoid of real valued functions because the identity elements are different.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now the first requirement. For the second one, I am not sure what $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ means. I've never seen that notation. Can you tell me, please?

Comment: @NAlex $A^B$  is the set of all functions from $B\to A$.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious candidate to show that $M$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are isomorphic would be $\phi:M \to \mathbb{N}$ by $\phi(f_n)=n$. Are any of the isomorphism properties difficult to prove? 
As for the second question, what is your definition of submonoid and again are any of the properties difficult to prove?

Comment: It's actually not a submonoid.